# how can i pass value in geo-autocomplete

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps

i am using geo-autocomplete that display street,state, country etc . But problem is that when user start to type anything that display the result for all over the word street or state . So i place two dropdown on my html page one for Country and one for State and i want that geo-autocomplete find value on selected country and  state means that will not display all country result .

[from here i download geo code of google](https://code.google.com/p/geo-autocomplete/)

that i am using in my code .

Answer (score 0):

Use the `geocoder_region` option to filter by country or state.

Comment: Following the link you provided: http://geo-autocomplete.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demo/ui.demo.html

Comment: sorry :( i don't understand in that how to pass my value like country or state from my dropdown in that can you help me ..